# Hardest optimization problems in NC

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, optimization, linear-programming

When learning optimization problems, we usually consider linear programming (or more generally: convex optimization) as the simplest example. It is solvable in polynomial time, and has relatively easy to understand algorithms. However, the decision version of LP is $\mathsf{P}$-complete. This suggests that it is one of the hardest problems we can solve in polynomial time.

Under the assumption that $\mathsf{NC} \neq \mathsf{P}$. **What is the 'hardest' natural kind of optimization problems with decision problems in $\mathsf{NC}$?**

If this is too vague, then we can restrict to restrictions. **What is the minimal set of restrictions we need to place on linear programs (or more generally: convex programs) to allow the decision problem associated with the restricted programs to be solvable in $\mathsf{NC}$?**

---

#### Motivation

To a large extent, this is idle curiosity. However, it was brought about by Cosma Shalizi's "[In Soviet Union, Optimization Problem Solves You](http://crookedtimber.org/2012/05/30/in-soviet-union-optimization-problem-solves-you/)". In particular, if LP is too difficult to solve to have a centralized economy (i.e. optimizing in $\mathsf{P}$ is asking too much), then any decentralized system must be doing some sort of parallel processing faster than poly-time (for me: $\mathsf{NC}$).

Comment: Because NC is a hierarchy, you are unlikely to find a "hardest" problem in NC (more precisely: NC does not have complete problems unless the NC hierarchy collapses). Similarly, there is probably not a "universal" *minimal* set of restrictions on LP to put it into NC, although this seems harder to rule out, even conditioned on natural assumptions. (This is not to detract from the question - I like the question, and it obviously produced some interesting answers - just a remark.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you aware of the work on positive LPs/SDPs? There are a bunch of results in the area, mostly along the lines of "if the constraints of the LP/SDP are positive, then the problem can be solved in NC."

Some important references in this line of work are [Luby-Nisan 93](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=167211) and [Jain-Yao 11](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2502). Another excellent resource is [this slide of Rahul Jain's talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Mf-KQmUJwA&t=7m0s) at the "Recent Progress in Quantum Algorithms" conference at IQC. The entire talk is available on youtube.

Comment: More precisely, Positive Linear Programming and Positive Semidefinite Programming are optimization problems that are not only exactly solvable in polynomial time (that is, they are in $\mathsf{PO}$), but also admit $\mathsf{NC}$ approximation schemes. They are not solvable exactly in $\mathsf{NC}$ (that is, in $\mathsf{NCO}$) unless $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NC}$.

Comment: @argentpepper where is reference that positive SDP and LP is $P$-complete?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but you may be interested - if not, I beg your pardon - to the following [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.10027/abstract), which is not related to a natural kind of optimization problem, but deals with a problem which can be reduced to a particular optimization problem, whose solution is in NC.

Igor Averbakh, Oded Berman, "Parallel NC-algorithms for multifacility location problems with mutual communication and their applications", Networks, Volume 40, Issue 1, pages 1–12, August 2002, Wiley

DOI: 10.1002/net.10027

Abstract

The generic problem studied is to locate p distinguishable facilities on a tree to satisfy upper-bound constraints on distances between pairs of facilities, given that each facility must be located within its own feasible region, which is defined as a subtree of the tree. We present a parallel location scheme (PLS) for solving the problem that can be implemented as an NC-algorithm. We also introduce parallel NC-algorithms based on the PLS for the minimax versions of the problem, including the distance-constrained p-center problem with mutual communication. Combining the PLS and the improved Megiddo's parametric technique, we develop strongly polynomial serial algorithms for the minimax problems; the algorithms have the best complexities currently available in the literature. Efficient parallel algorithms are given for obtaining optimal regions of the facilities.